# Error on $q Even though it is injected in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting an error (it doesn't give me an error description for some reason) whenever I hit the following line in my function:

```
 var deferred = $q.defer();
```

Function is called with this:

```
        var promise = saveAccessPermissions($scope.form.permissions, $scope.form);
    promise.then(function () {
        alert('items saved');
    })
```

Here is entire function, but it never gets past the `$q`.

```
function saveAccessPermissions(permissions, form) {

var deferred = $q.defer();
var permissionCount = 0;
function saveAccess() {
    form.AccessListItemPropertyId = permissions[permissionCount].AccessListItemPropertyId;
    PermissionsService.insertEmployeeAccess(form)
        .then(function () {
            permissionCount++;
            if (permissionCount < permissions.length) {
                return saveAccess();
            }
            else {
                deferred.resolve();
            }
        }).error(function (reason) {
            alert(reason);
        });
}
```

}

This is the way I have always used it, but it is erroring out on that line.  I have injected it into my controller:

```
 angular.module('myModule').controller('PermissionsCtrl', PermissionsCtrl);
PermissionsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'PermissionsService', '$filter', '$q', '$http'];
function PermissionsCtrl($scope, PermissionsService, $filter, $q, $http) {
```

I'm not sure what I am missing.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a plunker or some context? how is the method called?

Comment: I added all of the code.  I'm still working on function but, it errors as soon as it hits $q.defer();

Comment: how did you know there is an error ?

Comment: it goes to error module in Angularjs, it just does not give a description as (e) is null in         } catch (e) {
          $exceptionHandler(e);

Comment: Have you tried isolating the issue by creating an empty function that just has the line `$q.defer();` ?

Comment: Yes I did do that.  Same problem.  Could this possibly be caused by an old version of jQuery?  I'm just trying to consider possible causes.

Comment: There's no such thing as `.error`. Also, it seems that you're using deferred antipattern. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . If there's an error, it has to be replicated. It's unclear what's going on.